# Increase margins only above section headings

Tags: section-titles

I want to change the spacing above a section heading so that there is a larger top margin. I considered using a combination of `\voffest` and `\textheight` to do this, but those are global options and mess up placement of images later in the document, so I'd rather avoid that if possible.

I found the following commands:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{2.5in}{4in}{0in}
```

The first and third options of `\titlespacing` seem to do what they're supposed to, but the second one, which I suspected might be the answer to my problem, seems to do nothing. There is no text above this heading and googling has not found any useful answers for this particular problem.

Is there another way to change the spacing around headings or is there an easy fix for that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem only yesterday. My command now looks like this

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.2em plus 0.1em minus 0.4em}{0em plus 0.1em minus 0.2em}
```

Honestly I have no idea why my command is with the asterisk *, but it works for me. It seems important to give a margin with plus and minus so that LaTeX has some freedom to fill the pages better (this is called *glue* as I learned yesterday).

Comment: I might have come to a similar realization, but with a different command. I had been using \vspace and the whitespace kept getting deleted until I used \vspace*. Solved my problem